# I'm trying to embed Gecko or WebKit in a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, webkit, browser, gecko

I'm trying to make a web browser in Java, using Swing, but I can't seem to find any good way to embed WebKit or Gecko. I am currently using JEditorPane.getPage() but that's pretty useless for me. I am not very experienced with Java, just started learning this month. Anyway, if it's possible, I'd like it to be system-independent. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not `Desktop#browse()`?

Comment: What's that? If that opens the user's browser it's not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JavaFX's WebPane at the moment. That's fine for my needs. Close?